# Extract email from string using Template Tookit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I'm guessing this is relatively simple, but I can't find the answer.

From a string such as `'"John Doe" <email@example.com>'` - how can I extract the email portion from it using [Template Tookit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/)?

An example string to parse is this:

```
$VAR1 = { 
    'date' => '2021-03-25',
    'time' => '03:58:18',
    'href' => 'https://example.com',
    'from' => 'fezius@evrostroyserov.ru on behalf of Caroline <fezius@evrostroyserov.ru>',
    'bytes' => 13620,
    'pmail' => 'user@example.com',
    'sender' => 'sender@example.com',
    'subject' => 'Some Email Subject'
};
```

My code, based on [@dave-cross](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787489/888462) help below where `$VAR1` is the output of `dumper.dump(item.from)`

```
[% text = item.from -%]
[% IF (matches = text.match('(.*?)(\s)?+<(.*?)>')) -%]
<td>[% matches.1 %]</td>
[% ELSE -%]
<td>[% text %]</td>
[% END %]
```

However, it's still not matching against `$VAR1`

Comment: Template Toolkit is used to populate webpages or any other structured documents, not to extract information from text.

Comment: Tell us more about what you're trying to achieve and maybe we can help.

Comment: I probably should have used the word "format" instead of extract. Maybe a regex in TT to get the email only?

Comment: It is not clear what you try to do. If you try to extract name and email from the string then something of kind `my $data = '"John Doe" <email@example.com>'; my($name,$email) = $data =~ /"(.+?)" <(.+?)>/;` will produce desired result.

Comment: @DarioZadro: See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want, but it's pretty fragile and this really isn't the kind of thing that you should be doing in TT code. You should either get the data parsed outside of the template and passed into variables, or you should pass in a parsing subroutine that can be called from inside the template.

But, having given you the caveats, if you still insist this is what you want to do, then this is how you might do it:

In `test.tt`:

```
[% text = '"John Doe" <email@example.com>';
   matches = text.match('"(.*?)"\s+<(.*?)>');
   IF matches -%]
Name: [% matches.0 %]
Email: [% matches.1 %]
[% ELSE -%]
No match found
[% END -%]
```

Then, testing using `tpage`:

```
$ tpage test.tt
Name: John Doe
Email: email@example.com
```

But I cannot emphasise enough that you should not be doing it like this.

**Update:** I've used this test template to investigate your further problem.

```
[% item = { from => '"John Doe" <email@example.com>' };
   text = item.from -%]
[% IF (matches = text.match('(.*?)(\s)?+<(.*?)>')) -%]
<td>[% matches.1 %]</td>
[% ELSE -%]
<td>[% text %]</td>
[% END %]
```

And running it, I get this:

```
$ tpage test2.tt
<td> </td>
```

That's what I'd expect to see for a match. You're printing `matches.1`. That's the *second* item from the `matches` array. And the second match group is `(\s)`. So I'm getting the space between the name and the opening angle bracket.

You probably don't want that whitespace match in your `matches` array, so I'd remove the parentheses around it, to make the regex `(.*?)\s*<(.*?)>` (note that `\s*` is a simpler way to say "zero or more whitespace characters").

You can now use `matches.0` to get the name and `matches.1` to get the email address.

Oh, and there's no need to copy `items.from` into `text`. You can call the `matches` vmethod on any scalar variable, so it's probably simpler to just use:

```
[% matches = item.from.match(...) -%]
```

Did I mention that this is all a really terrible idea? :-)

**Update2**:

This is all going to be far easier if you give me complete, runnable code examples in the same way that I am doing for you. Any time I have to edit something in order to get an example running, we run the risk that I'm guessing incorrectly how your code works.

But, bearing that in mind, here's my latest test template:

```
[% item = {
    'date' => '2021-03-25',
    'time' => '03:58:18',
    'href' => 'https://example.com',
    'from' => 'fezius@evrostroyserov.ru on behalf of Caroline <fezius@evrostroyserov.ru>',
    'bytes' => 13620,
    'pmail' => 'user@example.com',
    'sender' => 'sender@example.com',
    'subject' => 'Some Email Subject'
};
   text = item.from -%]
[% IF (matches = text.match('(.*?)(\s)?<(.*?)>')) -%]
<td>[% matches.2 %]</td>
[% ELSE -%]
<td>[% text %]</td>
[% END %]
```

I've changed the definition of `item` to have your full example. I've left the regex as it was before my suggestions. And (because I haven't changed the regex) I've changed the output to print `matches.2` instead of `matches.1.`

And here's what happens:

```
$ tpage test3.tt
<td>fezius@evrostroyserov.ru</td>
```

So it works.

If yours doesn't work, then you need to identify the differences between my (working) code and your (non-working) code. I'm happy to help you identify those differences, but you have to give my your non-working example in order for me to do that.

**Update3**:

Again I've tried to incorporate the changes that you're talking about. But again, I've had to guess at stuff because you're not sharing complete runnable examples. And again, my code works as expected.

```
[% USE dumper -%]
[% item = {
    'date' => '2021-03-25',
    'time' => '03:58:18',
    'href' => 'https://example.com',
    'from' => 'fezius@evrostroyserov.ru on behalf of Caroline <fezius@evrostroyserov.ru>',
    'bytes' => 13620,
    'pmail' => 'user@example.com',
    'sender' => 'sender@example.com',
    'subject' => 'Some Email Subject'
};
 -%]
[% matches = item.from.match('(.*?)(\s)?<(.*?)>') -%]
[% dumper.dump(matches) %]
```

And testing it:

```
$ tpage test4.tt
$VAR1 = [
          'fezius@evrostroyserov.ru on behalf of Caroline',
          ' ',
          'fezius@evrostroyserov.ru'
        ];
```

So that works. If you want any more help, then send a complete runnable example. If you don't do that, I won't be able to help you any more.

Comment: This is getting me much closer. I'll update my question, and hopefully, you can provide an answer to solve my case.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. Unfortunately, the `matches` variable is always empty when calling `dumper.dump(matches)`. I'm giving up on this direction now, but will accept your answer since it's the most helpful.

Comment: @DarioZadro: How does your example code differ from mine? If you can show me more of your code, I'll try to work out what's going on.

Comment: I updated the `$VAR1` to see a true example to parse. My code is exactly what you provided. Let me know if that helps and much appreciated.

Comment: @DarioZadro: I don't know what you mean by "I updated the `$VAR1` to see a true example to parse". `$VAR1` is just dummy output created by Data::Dumper. There's no actual variable called `$VAR1`. Can you share some actual code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I updated my original question above to show exactly what `item.from` contains as a real example. My code is exactly what you provided, but again, the `matches` variable is empty.

Comment: This is my code for testing purposes ` [% matches = item.from.match('(.*?)(\s)?<(.*?)>') -%]` and then this `[% dumper.dump(matches) %]` shows an empty $VAR1 output. It appears the "match" is not working for some reason. Oh well, thanks again.

Comment: @DarioZadro: That's not your code. That is a couple of small extracts from your code. If you want more help, please provide your code in a complete, runnable format in the same way I've been doing for you.

Comment: I've mentioned a few times that my code is exactly the same as the code you are providing. Must be a difference in our environments or something else not covered here.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very old (and unmaintained) module, [Template::Extract](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Extract), that let's you define a template, then work backward from a string that might have been produced by that template:

```
use Template::Extract;
use Data::Dumper;

my $obj = Template::Extract->new;
my $template = qq("[% name %]" <[% email %]>);

my $string = '"John Doe" <email@example.com>';

my $extracted = $obj->extract($template, $string);

print Dumper( $extracted );
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'email' => 'email@example.com',
          'name' => 'John Doe'
        };
```

However, there are modules that already do this job for you and will handle many more situations

Comment: This looks like it's on the right track, but how would you do this in a `.tt` template file?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do this at all. Inside a template file, you have access to all of Perl, so you can write whatever Perl you want. However, you should be figuring all this stuff out before  you process the template so you just pass the values you need. I think you'll need to explain why you are doing things inside out before anyone might comment on what you are doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to the template file. Can you edit your answer to show how the same can be accomplished directly in the `.tt` file? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see an active plugin on http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/index.html and not sure your answer will work.

Comment: My answer is as far as I care to take it. Again, I don't recommend you use it and instead state your actual problem to get better advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how Template Toolkit can help you. Use [Email::Address](http://p3rl.org/Email::Address) or [Email::Address::XS](http://p3rl.org/Email::Address::XS) to parse an e-mail address.